# What to do when I don't plan to edit my *on hold* question? Delete? Maintain?

Tags: discussion

My question is on hold and I'm not going to change it. Should I delete it or just keep it there because the comments link to relevant discussions?

The question - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298594/recommended-way-to-store-a-distributed-project-in-git?noredirect=1#comment620378_298594

Comment: You could just delete it, if it's at 0 or lower it'll get auto deleted eventually anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, the system will delete questions. See the Meta Stack Exchange questions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/572) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/572). However, at present, the automatic deletion does not pick up questions that have 1 or more up-votes (like your question does now).

What you do is up to you, but if the question is not a good fit for the site and people come across it in the various review queues or during other activities, they may down vote it, causing you to lose reputation. If you aren't going to fix it, I'd probably delete it.